# Western Digital external HDD not showing up in Finder & Disk Utility

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, external-disk

I'm running Sonoma 14.2.1 on a late 2021 Macbook Pro.

I just purchased a new Western Digital Easy Store 2TB External HDD. I plugged it into my mac (I do need a USB-B to C adapter) and my mac asked if I wanted to connect the device and I clicked "yes." But the device does not show up in Finder nor Disk Utility.

Can anyone advise how to debug this issue?

Comment: Disk Utility > View menu > Enable "Show all devices". Do you see the drive now?

Comment: any lights on the external drive, any noise

Comment: @Gilby Show All Devices was already checked

Comment: @Ruskes No noise. The lights are on. I don't think the HDD is corrupted. It's brand new

Comment: so. it gets power ! AFIK the USB-B is a printer cable

Comment: @Ruskes What do you mean by printer cable? The cable came with the external HDD, and I use an adapter to connect to USB-C

Comment: Show me a picture

Comment: did you use a cable or a adapter, it is called `micro usb type b` so you might have defective adapter

Comment: @Ruskes I used an adapter. I also tried 2 docker stations. Same issue with all 3

Comment: What is your Finder >Preferences>General settings